# datatrigger causing button to be misaligned

Tags: wpf, button, styles, datatrigger, isenabled

When I remove this style from a button it displays properly.  When I don't, it pushes all the other buttons in the row down by approx 5 pixels.

```
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanUserUpdateHosts}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have any implicit Styles defined for Buttons, then they will be ignored if you set the Button.Style property explicitly. So chances are you are short-circuiting another Style.

Default Styles on the other hand will still be applied.